# Specify special case handler for MapRoute in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, maproute

I have the following Route defined in Global.asax:

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "IncidentActionWithId", // Route name
                "Incidents/{companyId}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
                new { controller = "Incidents" } // Parameter defaults
            );
```

I have a special case of request, like this one:

```
/Incidents/SuperCompany/SearchPeople/Ko
```

In this case, action should indeed map to `SearchPeople` action, `comapnyId` to this action's parameter, but only when action is SearchPeople, the `Ko` should not be mapped to an id parameter of the action, but to `searchTerm`.

My action declaration is:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult SearchPeople(string companyId, string searchTerm)
```

How can I achieve `Ko` to be mapped to `searchTerm` parameter in my action method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define two routes, one with `id` and one with `searchTerm` **if** the id is supposed to be numeric (or you can specify regex **constratints**) and have different pattern to searchTerm.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992978.aspx) how you can define constraints.

Example:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "IncidentActionWithId", // Route name
            "Incidents/{companyId}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Incidents" }, // Parameter defaults
            new {id = @"\d+"} // numeric only
        );

routes.MapRoute(
            "IncidentActionWithId", // Route name
            "Incidents/{companyId}/{action}/{searchterm}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Incidents" } 
        );
```

## NOTE

Define the one with constraint first.